# Insert Data in Parent table and then inserting parent primary key in child table

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am doing my final year project and we are stated to follow object oriented approach during design and development.

My question is: I have a parent table `User`:

```
public partial class User
```

This table has its attributes.

Then I have a child table `Advertiser`:

```
public partial class Advertiser : User
```

I am using EF6. Now please tell me approach how to save data into the `User` table and then take the `UserID` and paste it into the `Advertiser` table.

**Problem**

When I do this

```
Advertiser.AdvertiserID = User.UserID;

db.SaveChanges();
```

Then it says provide all the values of `Advertiser` class which came into existence due to inheritance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `User` and `Advertiser` have a relationship in database, you might have `Advertiser` in `User` POCO for one-to-one relationship.

```
public partial class User
{
   public User() {..}    
   ...
   public virtual Advertiser Advertiser { get; set; }
}
```

If so, you could just call `SaveChanges` once. They become transaction.

```
user.Advertiser = new Advertiser 
{
    // No need to assign value to AdvertiserID
    FirstName = "John",
    LastName = "Doe"
}; 
db.Users.Add(user);
db.SaveChanges();
```

Otherwise, they do not have relationship in database. You will have to save one after another.

```
db.Users.Add(user);
db.SaveChanges();

advertiser.AdvertiserID = user.UserID; // UserID is filled with newly created ID
db.Advertiser.Add(advertiser);
db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Thanks for quick response but as i said I have to implement object oriented approach so there is one thing also coming into existence that is "class Advertiser:User". So entity framework force me to do advertiser.FirstName. FirstName came from User table that is already inserted in database. But if I try to insert data using advertiser table then I also got failed.

Comment: You can not have this thing: `class Advertiser:User`. It is wrong. Child table don't must be inherited from parent table

Comment: But i have shown this thing in class diagram so how I am going to defend this thing in front of project team. Tips will be highly appreciated. Thanks again.

Comment: @DanishShabbir As Alexcei said, we don't do inheritance in Entity Framework; POCO entities do not necessary need to reflect Class Diagram. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

In your example, the relationship between advertiser and user isn't parent-child, it is inheritance. EF supports three models for inheritance: table per type, table per hierarchy, and table per concrete instance. To get a better understanding on how these are set up, and how their schema will look you can reference (https://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-1-table-per-hierarchy-tph) which has links for all three, or Google EF and TPT/TPH/TPC for alternative examples. (DB-First)

In all casses, Advertiser's PK would be UserID. With considering inheritance vs. composition the question is whether the relationship is an "Is a" or a "Has a". Is an advertiser a user, or does an advertiser have a user? I would guess that Is-A is an accurate relationship.

In an Is-A relationship, all entities that "are" users would have PK's of "UserId". (whether there is a Users base table or not) In a Has-A relationship, such as an Advertiser has an Address, then you would consider relationships like a many-to-1 or 1-to-1 where Advertiser has an AddressID to point to an address record, or a many-to-many there is a joining table of UserID and AddressID to link the two together.

As long as you keep these relationships consistent, EF configuration should be pretty straight forward.